# GraphQL / Apollo: "No Schemas available". NodeJS

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, graphiql

I`m trying to work with GraphQL/Apollo, and my "Documentation Explorer" loading infinitely and doesnt show anything, and i can't make any queries.

[image]

After few minutes I getting an typeError `"Failed to fetch"`.

Here's my `graphql/index.js` file:

```
const { graphqlExpress, graphiqlExpress } = require('apollo-server-express');
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require('graphql-tools');
const User = require('../models/user.model');

const typeDefs = `

  type Query {
    users: [User]
  }

  type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    email: String
    password: String
  }

`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    users() {
      return User.find({});
    }
  }
}

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.use('/graphql', () => { }, graphqlExpress({ schema }));

  app.use('/graphiql', graphiqlExpress({ endpointURL: '/graphql' }));
};
```

Console and DevTools both clear. Can someone explain, what`s wrong? Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you were trying to accomplish, but you've added a middleware to your `/graphql` route that does nothing:

```
app.use('/graphql', () => { }, graphqlExpress({ schema }))
```

The function you've inserted gets called anytime something hits the `/graphql` route, and because your function doesn't call `next` or end the response, the next middleware (`graphqlExpress`) is never called and the request just hangs.

The other problem is that `graphqlExpress` requires bodyParser middleware to run before it's called. That means you can do either:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

// Option A -- body parser will run prior to all routes after this point
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// Option B -- body parser will only run for the graphql route
app.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), graphqlExpress({ schema }))
```

If you fail to include bodyParser, graphqlExpress will typically complain and tell you as much as long you actually reach it in the first place.